# Using a background image to model in Blender

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, image

I have chosen the book BlenderBasics_4thEdition2011.pdf to use in teaching my first 3D Animation Class using Blender.  In it, on page 38, there is a lesson that uses a background image as a guide to create a 3D logo.  The text says to scroll down on the Transfom Panel to find the "Background Images" panel.  I cannot find that panel.  I have downloaded the latest Blender 2.72 release.

Can someone help me with this please?  I have done a couple Google searches and found images of that panel but I can't seem to find it on the Transform panel.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Press [N] to open the properties tab; You'll find it there.

Comment: Thank you!  Pressing N was the key.  It is obvious I am a novice to Blender but I am learning.  I appreciate the quick reply.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the properties panel on the right side of the 3D view (if it is not already open)  Then scroll down till you see backround images and click *add image*.  To see the image you must be in orthographic mode and a side view, press<kbd>numpad 5</kbd> to toggle orthographic/perspective mode and <kbd>numpad 1/3/7</kbd> to go into a side view.