# Smart UV Project Problem

Tags: texturing, uv

So I want to texture my model using smart UV Project but when I make the smart UV project my reference image keeps popping in the background of the UV.
How do I make my reference image disappear?

Comment: It seems to be that your problem isn't with Smart UV Project, rather thatn with turning off background / reference image. About background images see this - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing or this - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19751/using-a-background-image-to-model-in-blender

Comment: To be honest its the article in the site you given me is not helping

Comment: If you solved your question then please post your solution as an answer so others may benefit from this.